# Buttons randomly shift after minimise/restore on form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am completely stumped, when I minimise and then restore my main form window some of my form buttons move behind other buttons.

I have not overridden any of the functions that govern this so I am totally confused as to why this would happen.

My components are all anchored and set to "bottom right" yet they magically teleport to the right after a minimise/restore. This is what  mean:

[image: Before]
[image: After]
I dont end know where to start looking for ways to fix this because a google search didn't turn up anything. Has anyone experienced anything like this? What could it be due to?

Comment: Start analyzing from `Document Outline window` of VS.

Comment: Which panels are you using ??

Comment: Hey guys I managed to fix it by nesting everything inside table panels or split panels